# Communicate between MainWindow and custom classes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What is the best way to communicate between the `MainWindow` and other custom classes in WPF?

Let's say we have this structure.

```
- MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.xaml.cs

- MyClass.cs
```

I have used the `Class1.cs` in `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
<drawings:MyClass>
   .
   .
   .
</drawings:MyClass>
```

In `MyClass` I have a variable called `X`, now what is the best way to access this variable from `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

I know I'm missing something very obvious about object oriented programming here, I just don't know what it is.

**Update:**
Here is the code I have put up together so far, but it doesn't work. And the value of TextBlock doesn't change.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="CustomClasses.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:customclasses="clr-namespace:CustomClasses"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <customclasses:MyClass></customclasses:MyClass>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <customclasses:MyClass Width="525" Height="350" Background="Blue">
        </customclasses:MyClass>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MyClass:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CustomClasses
{
    class MyClass : Border
    {
        public double X { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            MouseMove += MyMouseMove;
        }

        private void MyMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var b = (Border) sender;
            X = Mouse.GetPosition(b).X;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look at the various tutorials online for the MVVM Pattern e.g.[MVVM tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html)

Comment: Do you want the variable in the MyClass,to bind it to any control(textbox,lable) in the MainWindow.?

Comment: @NullReferenceException Yes, I want to show the value of the X in textbox.label in MainWindow

Comment: @Vahid - Where have you declared the instance in XAML? Under resources section OR it's set as DataContext to some control?

Comment: @RohitVats I updated the full code I have written so far.

Comment: @Vahid - I have added an answer in response to your edit. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested in accessing `X` for the instance which you have declared inside Grid i.e.

```
<customclasses:MyClass Width="525" Height="350" Background="Blue">
</customclasses:MyClass>
```

I would say set `x:Name` on this instance and then you can access it in code behind by this name.

```
<customclasses:MyClass x:Name="myClass" Width="525" Height="350"
                       Background="Blue"/>
```

and in code behind you can access it like this:

```
double value = myClass.X;
```

---

In case interested in getting X for DataContext instance i.e.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <customclasses:MyClass></customclasses:MyClass>
</Window.DataContext>
```

you can get value in code behind like this:

```
double value = ((MyClass)DataContext).X;
```

---

### UPDATE

**First** of all `MyClass` declared as DataContext and defined under Grid are two separate instances. Remove DataContext and bind using `ElementName` with instance declared inside Grid.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:MyClass x:Name="myClass" Width="525" Height="350" Background="Blue"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding X, ElementName=myClass}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Second** for UI to update your class `MyClass` should implement [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that any change in UI property gets reflected back on UI.

**MyClass**:

```
class MyClass : Border, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            if (x != value)
            {
                x = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        MouseMove += MyMouseMove;
    }

    private void MyMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var b = (Border)sender;
        X = Mouse.GetPosition(b).X;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the Binding part still doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something either in XAML or MyClass.cs

Comment: Thank you so much Rohit Vats, I learned a lot and I actually got started with MVVM.

Comment: How can I pass an object to MyClass? Is it done via MVVM too? Let's say I have an object in the MainWindow.xaml.cs, how can I pass it to MyClass?

Comment: You can do data binding for that. Read more here - [Data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You mean I should bind the MyClass to what? I have hard time understanding these concepts :( I asked it as a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581508/pass-an-object-from-mainwindow-to-a-customclass

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access it from another class in your cs file then you need to create object of your class and access the variable

```
         MyClass _m=new MyClass();
        _m.x=//Your value
```

But if you are trying to access it from your `.cs` file to `XAML`

then you can add your variable as a **resource**.

```
   MainWindow.Resources.Add("resourceKey",_yourvariable);
```

and in XAML

```
  <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource resourceKey}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you plan to use Methods/Variables of MyClass within MainWindow as well as across the project,
 
You could declare a member in MainWindow class like this:

```
private static MyClass _myClassVar = null;

public static MyClass myClassVar 
{
    get
    {
        if (_myClassVar  == null)
            _myClassVar = new MyClass();

            return _myClassVar;
    }
}
```

You can then call public members of MyClass as: 
MainWindow.myClassVar.X

As I read from the comments.
In case you need to capture changes in variables of MyClass, please read on **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window .......
   xmlns:drawings="clr-namespace:YourAppName.FolderName(If YourClass In folder)">
<Window.DataContext>
    <drawings:MyClass> //MyClass is the name of the class
</Window.DataContext>
   .
   .
   .
  <TextBox Text={Binding X,Mode=TowWay} . . . . />
</Window>
```

In Your MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
   _private int _x;
   public int X
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Now if you assign value to X here that will bind to TextBox.

Reference : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx

Comment: Thanks, is this the MVVM approach everybody is talking about? What about when we have more than one custom classes? How will we define the DataContext then?

Comment: In general yes, but it may also vary from programmers to programmers.Consider if you have two Layout Panels in MainWindow, then you can give DataContext to Layout Panels with two custom classes you created.

Comment: I put up the code together with your help, I think I'm missing something the value of TextBlock is always 0 and doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

simple...declare variable as static in MyClass and use it in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
class MyClass
{
//public static int x=10;
 public int x;
   public MyClass()
   {
      x=10;
   }
}

public MainWindow.xaml.cs
{
        //messageBox.show("x="+MyClass.x);
       Myclass obj=new MyClass();
       messageBox.show("x="+obj.x);
 }
```

Comment: I can't define it as Static.

Comment: ok if you can't declare it as static then you can create an obj of MyClass

Comment: @MohiniMhetre The value of X is constantly changing in MyClass, then if create an obj of MyClass it will be lost?

Comment: then static is the solution for that