# Pass an object from MainWindow to a CustomClass

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I pass an object from `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to `MyClass.cs` ?

```
- MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.xaml.cs

- MyClass.cs
- Building.cs
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var b = new Building();
        b.Name = "My Building";
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="CustomClasses.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:customclasses="clr-namespace:CustomClasses"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <customclasses:MyClass x:Name="myClass">
        </customclasses:MyClass>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? There might be better solution to achieve that.

Comment: I have defined an object in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs' that contains lots of data. And `MyClass` needs this data so I guess I need to pass this data to that class. right?

Comment: Yeah ideally your `MyClass` should have declared `dependency properties` so that you can bind data to it from some other class. How much data we are talking here? In the posted question I can see only one object.

Comment: @RohitVats The `Building.cs` contains lots of properties/methods/dictionaries that are loaded from a text file. For now, I have defined it as static but I don't know if it is a good idea or should I define it some other way?

Comment: I have added an answer for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one object you are interested in you can declare `Dependency Property` in MyClass and can bind through XAML.

```
public class MyClass : Border
{
    public Building MyBuilding
    {
        get { return (Building)GetValue(MyBuildingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBuildingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBuildingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBuilding", typeof(Building),
                                     typeof(MyClass));

}
```

and in `MainWindow`, you have to declare property of type Building:

```
public Building MyBuilding { get; set;}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    MyBuilding = new Building();
    b.Name = "My Building";
}
```

In case `MyBuilding` can change over the application execution make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on MainWindow class and property changed event is raised whenever MyBuilding gets set.

**XAML**

```
<customclasses:MyClass x:Name="myClass" MyBuilding="{Binding MyBuilding}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign property from `MyClass` in code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var b = new Building();
        b.Name = "My Building";

        myClass.MyBuilding = b;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public Building MyBuilding {get; set;}
}
```